# Gnome 'createThumbnail' overloads CPU

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I had installed the following extension on Gnome, [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/). After which, I restarted Gnome by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and restart.

Now my Gnome doesn't display any images or icons (even at the login screen) 
and syslog shows a lot of entries of the form:

```
createThumbnail[3120]: Failed to create thumbnail "~/. cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail factory/...": Image type "png" is not supported.
```

I believe the `createThumbnail` process is forked again in an infinite loop and causes the system to hang and overheat.